# MessageDigest.update() before digest()?

Tags: java, hash

I have found the following example code (somewhere on the web, can't remember where):

```
public static byte[] produce(final byte[] data)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    digest.reset();
    digest.update(data);
    byte[] ret = digest.digest(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_ITERATIONS; i++) {
        digest.reset();
        ret = digest.digest(ret);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

What bothers me is that the docs says that digest() already calls update() on its own with the passed input:

> Performs a final update on the digest using the specified array of
>   bytes, then completes the digest computation. That is, this method
>   first calls update(input), passing the input array to the update
>   method, then calls digest().

Additionally, after the call to update(), the MessageDigest object's `state` becomes `1`.
After a call to digest() (next in the code) it returns to be simply `0`.
Finally, when stepping through while debugging, I can clearly see that the data is being manipulated.

So, is it safe to remove the call to update()?

Note that I wouldn't bother anyone with that question if it weren't a big security issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right, it is safe to remove `update` in your code. And more, by calling `update(data)` and then calling `digest(data)` you actually calculating digest of different message that contains `data` twice. I think is not what you need.

The common use case of `digest(byte[])` is calculation of digest of complete data block (i.e. password). The `update(byte[])` in pair with `digest()` used when you need to calculate digest of data coming by parts:

```
int read = 0; 
while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    md.update(buffer, 0, read);
};
byte[] digest  = md.digest();
```